# Write a Java code that accepts strings from the command line and displays its characters in alphabetical order

Tags: java, string, command, reverse

The word `COMPUTER` should be display as `CEMOPRTU`.

The string should be accepted from the command line-

```
class sortstr
{


         public static void main(String args[])
         {

                  int len=args.length;


                  if(len==0)
                  {


                         System.out.println("No arguments are given ! ");

                         return;

                  }




                  char[] str=args[0].toCharArray();

                 char temp;




                  for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
                  {

                      for(int j=0;j<len-1;j++)
                      {

                             // Swap the characters


                             if(str.charAt(j)> str.charAt(j+1))
                             {

                                   temp=str[j];

                                   str[j]=str[j+1];

                                   str[j+1]=temp;
                             }

                       }
                  }



                  for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
                  {

                       System.out.print(str[i]);

                  }




       }

}
```

Comment: So what you tried so far?  No-one is just going to give you code!

Comment: You should first try and give it a shot, if you fail to make any progress, give details on what you tried and in what way it failed. That is the whole point of having homework/assignments.

Comment: You mean return the word unscrambled ?

Answer (score 4):

Since this is homework, I can only suggest you answer yourself the following questions:

1) What standard Java class can be used for reading from the console?

2) What data structure will you use for the input string, in order to sort the chars in it later?

3) What library method allows sorting the data structure in (2) ?

Once you know the answers, all you have to do is let your fingers play on the keyboard...

Comment: NO...any library method are not allowed !!